# Core Plot-How to Convert Touch-Sensed Point to Point in PlotSpace?

Tags: ios, coordinates, core-plot

I'm new to core plot. I'm trying to calculate closest data point to the coordinate where touch is sensed in the code below:

```
-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDownEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    NSLog(@"touch sensed");
    NSLog(@"points: %f, %f",point.x,point.y);
    [self.distances removeAllObjects];

    CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
    if (symbolTextAnnotation) {
        [graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea removeAnnotation:symbolTextAnnotation];
        symbolTextAnnotation = nil;
    }
    CPTMutableTextStyle *hitAnnotationTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    hitAnnotationTextStyle.color    = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    hitAnnotationTextStyle.fontSize = 16.0;
    hitAnnotationTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    for(int i=0;i<[self.allX count];i++){
        //NSLog(@"-->all points: %@, %@", [self.allX objectAtIndex:i],[self.allY objectAtIndex:i]);
        NSLog(@"-->all points: %f, %f", [[self.allX objectAtIndex:i] floatValue],[[self.allY objectAtIndex:i] floatValue]);
        CGFloat xDist = (point.x - [[self.allX objectAtIndex:i] floatValue]);
        CGFloat yDist = (point.y - [[self.allY objectAtIndex:i] floatValue]);
        NSLog(@"-->all distances: %f, %f", xDist,yDist);
        CGFloat distance = sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist));
        NSNumber *distanceNum = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:distance];
        NSLog(@"-->total distance: %@", distanceNum);
        [self.distances addObject:distanceNum];
    }

    for(int i=0;i<[self.distances count];i++){
        NSLog(@"calculated distances: %@",[self.distances objectAtIndex:i]);
    }

    NSNumber *minDistance = [self.distances valueForKeyPath:@"@min.doubleValue"];
    NSLog(@"min distance: %@", minDistance);
    int index=[self.distances indexOfObject:minDistance];
    NSLog(@"cloest point: %@,%@",[self.allX objectAtIndex:index],[self.allY objectAtIndex:index]);

    NSArray *anchorPoint = @[[self.allX objectAtIndex:index], [self.allY objectAtIndex:index] ];

    CPTTextLayer *textLayer = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:@"LABEL" style:hitAnnotationTextStyle] ;
    symbolTextAnnotation              = [[CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation alloc] initWithPlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace anchorPlotPoint:anchorPoint];
    symbolTextAnnotation.contentLayer = textLayer;
    symbolTextAnnotation.displacement = CGPointMake(0.0, 20.0);
    [graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea addAnnotation:symbolTextAnnotation];

    return 1;
}
```

However, I just realized that touch coordinates returned by this method is not measured in the same system as the coordinates plotted on the graph. For example, touching coordinate (2,60) on the graph would return coordinates like (188,150), which are way off. Is there a way to find the equivalent of say (188,150) in the graph coordinate system?

Answer (score 0):

Use the plot space (passed as a parameter to this method) to convert between data coordinates and plot area view coordinates.

Use one of the following methods to extract the touch coordinates from the `event` and convert them to data coordinates.

```
-(void)plotPoint:(NSDecimal *)plotPoint numberOfCoordinates:(NSUInteger)count forEvent:(CPTNativeEvent *)event;
-(void)doublePrecisionPlotPoint:(double *)plotPoint numberOfCoordinates:(NSUInteger)count forEvent:(CPTNativeEvent *)event;
```

Alternatively, use the `-plotAreaViewPointForEvent:` method to extract the view coordinates of the touch point from the event and use one of the following methods to convert the data coordinates to view coordinates and calculate the distances in that coordinate system:

```
-(CGPoint)plotAreaViewPointForPlotPoint:(NSDecimal *)plotPoint numberOfCoordinates:(NSUInteger)count;
-(CGPoint)plotAreaViewPointForDoublePrecisionPlotPoint:(double *)plotPoint numberOfCoordinates:(NSUInteger)count;
```

Comment: I used the following code, similar to what you said:           NSDecimal plotPoint[2];
[space plotPoint:plotPoint forPlotAreaViewPoint:point];, but got no @interface declared for plotPoint:plotAreaViewPointForEvent

Comment: What version of Core Plot are you using? The "event" methods have been there since version 1.1 (1.5.1 is the latest release).